# PHP wp_mail smtp

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to develop a quick mail function, which when triggered sends a short email to the admin. When testing approximately 10 times I only received 2 emails, which took quite sometime to come through to my inbox. I'm aware that the host maybe blocking this type of mail feature, so I began looking into setting up a SMTP form and implementing the below into it. After 4 hours of trying to figure this out, I still haven't managed to setup a function that send several variables to an email address. I'm obviously doing something wrong, could somebody please point me in the right direction with this? Thank you.

**PHP**

```
$from = "xxx";
$to = "xxx";
$subject = "Subject";

/* Message */
$message = '<strong>Customer Details</strong><br/>';
$message .= 'Name: '. $first_name .' '. $last_name .'<br/>';
$message .= 'Email: '. $email .'<br/>';
$message .= 'Phone: '. $phone .'<br/>';
$message .= '<br/>';
$message .= '<strong>Order Details</strong><br/>';
$sub_ = $order->get_items();
foreach($sub_ as $sub){
  $message .= $sub['name'].'<br/>';
}

$header = "From:" . $from;
wp_mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress wp_mail() reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)

The `wp_mail()` does not support HTML content by default. You need to do `add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'text/html' );` before sending.